# Is it better to avoid emailing bad/negative news, if you can use phone communication?

Tags: communication, time-off

I'm in a situation where I've taken a hiatus from work, in order to complete schooling (I was an intern though, and after the degree I'm expecting to be FT). However, the hiatus will need more time than initially communicated(I told them I'd need only one month - til April 8, but life got in the way).  It will need 3 more months (til July).

I'm already scheduled to speak on the phone with my boss next week, however I feel tempted to email him today about the upcoming delay. But I am wary of emailing news like this (I'd likely get no response..), because it would certainly be discouraging and I feel it hurts my prospects of rejoining.

Should I just wait-and-see?

Comment: When I had a similar situation, I preferred the phone - I was working on trying to set a start date, and considering difficulties on my end outside my control were causing more work for my future manager, I made sure to have those conversations via phone.

Comment: Adding to enderlands, perhaps follow up with an email so there is a hard copy of the communications to refer to

Comment: @RhysW - Got it! Yes, I'll send a follow-up to express thanks and a summary.

Comment: @Adel just to be clear - I had a timeframe of several months at that point (not 3 days). We were talking about a date 3-6 months in the future.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Assuming there is reasonable timeframe

Considering you are talking on the phone with your future boss anyways, I would *strongly* suggest discussing this on the phone rather than email.

You will be able to do a much better job communicating what might be bad news.

### If you said you were a date three days from now originally for a start-date....

Now, if you are supposed to be starting work next Monday and are wondering how to tell him you need another three months starting only 3 days from now, you should call him as soon as you can - **literally right now** - leave a message and then send an email as well asking him to call you.

Make absolutely sure you have an honest answer to the question

- "Why didn't you tell me this earlier?"

because if this is the case (your question seems to imply this, unfortunately), you are probably going to be causing a huge headache for your future boss.